# Most lightweight way to return multiple values in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, code-analysis

I can think of two ways to do this:

- **Option 1** return an array of values
- **Option 2** create a class specific to the data type

In my specific case I am handling indicies of a martix. I want to analyze which is more lightweight:

**Option 1**

```java
new int[] {1, 2}
```

- 24 bytes for array
- 2 * 4 bytes for each int
- **Total** 32 bytes

**Option 2**

```java
private final class Location {
    public final int i;
    public final int j;

    public Location (int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

- 16 bytes for object
- 2 * 4 bytes for each int
- padding of 4 bytes to round up to multiple of 8
- **Total** 32 bytes

It seems they are equivalent in terms of memory is this correct?

Are there any other considerations for which is faster? e.g. Is it faster to access the `Location` object attribute or index an array? I am using 64 bit, java 6, is this relevant?

Comment: Have you considered returning a `long`? Those two ints would fit in there nicely :)

Comment: The object-oriented alternative (separate `class`) is much more readable, which makes it the preferred alternative, unless you have benchmarked this to be a performance bottleneck in your application.

Comment: What's your source on those numbers? AFAIK object header is 12 bytes, plus two ints, that's 20. Padding to alignment brings this to 24 bytes.

Comment: You shouldn't pre-optimize (make optimization choices before you know they're beneficial/needed/have affect). Profile your application to see which best fits what you want to do. Not to mention, this seems like micro-optimization (the time/memory saved would most likely be negligable). I'd personally choose the most readable version

Comment: And for arrays, it's the same object header + int length, 16 bytes. Plus two ints, 24 bytes.

Comment: I would say it does not matter as long as we are talking of bytes. Don't sacrifice readability of your code in favor of saving some bytes (perhaps)

Comment: This is for an assignment and memory usage is graded in bytes, so every byte is important

Comment: @VinceEmigh, agree although pre-optimisation is perfectly valid given pre-knowledge, for example that instantiating a class is more expensive than a single number lets say

Comment: Please apply http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Coder-Conduct-Professional-Programmers/dp/0137081073 to keep the code clean and readable. No performance tuning without knowing the timings.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to minimize the amount of heap allocation, the difference between array and object is of lesser significance. A much greater saving will be achieved if you design the API such that it isn't mandatory that each call allocates a new object. There are several approaches:

1. Rely on Escape Analysis to do its thing and place your object's data on the stack. Currently this only works for proper objects, not arrays.
2. Specify the contract such that the returned object is a singleton, shared for all method calls.
3. Design the API such that a mutable object is passed to the method and the method updates the object.

Option 1 has the disadvantage that it's unrealiable. You may or may not benefit from EA.

Option 2 has the disadvantage that you'll need to manually copy the data to some other place if you want to accumulate data from many calls.

Option 3 is the best because it puts the caller in control of what gets allocated and when. Anything can be hidden behind the abstraction of the type you pass in as the receptacle of data. It could e.g. push data directly into an output stream.

On a final note, if your question is actually very specific and only about returning two `int`s, then it does make sense to return a `long` and have helper methods that pry the two apart.

Comment: Hmmm, so true. I missed it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I heard that allocation can be eliminated for short arrays in C2. There's even JVM option `-XX:EliminateAllocationArraySizeLimit`.

Comment: I think I discussed that one with @Peter, too. He couldn't see it in actual testing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not for the char[] in a String which is usually built from a StringBuilder. This is a pretty common case, but a bit complex to optimise I image. If you do `byte[] b = { 0 };` perhaps this is optimised. In most applications the `char[]` is the most common or one of the most common objects, so it would be good to optimise it in some way. e.g. like compact string in Java 6 did.

Comment: @peter My guess is that only arrays with constant size stand a chance.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in C `alloca(n)` allow dynamic sizes. It would have to be fixed size to be assigned to a register, but if it's on the stack it could be any size. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Advantages-of-Alloca.html

Comment: @peter But would it compose with JVM's oopmaps and other stuff?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't imagine it uses `alloca`, just making the point that dynamic allocation on the stack has at at least one well understood solution.